# Angular 2 Barcode Generator

Tags: javascript, angular, barcode

I am looking for Angular 2 Barcode Generator for generate code 128 barcode. But I cant find it.

Is anyone available to help?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You can ref [yobryon/ngx-barcode](https://github.com/yobryon/ngx-barcode) An angular component for Angular 4+ for creating 1-D barcodes based on Lindell's JsBarcode

Comment: I tried that package. But i am getting error. i add my issue to repository. https://github.com/yobryon/ngx-barcode/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Online Barcode Api, (MIT License)
Link to the API : [BWIP Online Barcode API](https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js/wiki/Online-Barcode-API),
Link to the Github Page: [Github BWIP](https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js)